# Error "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations whilst defining methods"

Tags: c++, class, oop, header-files

I'm relatively new to C++ (so try and keep answers simple please!), and I can't understand why I get the error: ***`C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations whilst defining methods.`***

I am trying to write a simple program to read a text file line by line, store the values into an array. However I am encountering an issue when trying to declare methods in my .cpp file. Please find code below.

***StringList.h***

```
#ifndef StringListH
#define StringListH

#include <vector>
#include <string>

class StringList {
public:
     StringList();
     ~StringList();
     void PrintWords();
private:
     size_t numberOfLines;
     std::vector<std::string> str;
};

#endif
```

***StringList.cpp***

```
#include "StringList.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <algorithm> // std::copy
#include <iterator>  // istream_iterator

using namespace std;

StringList::StringList()
{
    ifstream myfile("input.in");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        copy(
            istream_iterator<string>(myfile),
            istream_iterator<string>(),
            back_inserter(str));
    }
    numberOfLines = str.size();
}

StringList::~StringList(){
    //Deconstructor
}

// Error Happens Here
StringList::PrintWords(){
    //Print My array
}
```

I have googled to no avail, I don't quite understand how to read the proper documentation for C++ yet, so I'm a little stuck. I have written around 3 or 4 (simple) object orientated programs so far and I've never had this issue. If it helps I'm using Xcode, but I get the same error in eclipse.

It appears any method, regardless of return type, name, parameters defined in my head file give this error - however the constructor is fine. If PrintWords() is remove the project builds just fine.

Any pointers will be very much appreciated!

Comment: You are lacking a return type for `StringList::PrintWords()`: it was declared as `void` but the type is omitted in the definition.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you declared it as `void` but you forgot to put it in the definition. should be:

`void StringList::PrintWords()`

Answer (score 6):

Put a `void` in front of the line giving you issues.

Even though it feels redundant, you have to specify the return type both in the declaration and the implementation.

Answer (score 6):

Your member function `PrintWords` is prototyped as:

```
void PrintOn();
```

Meaning it returns `void`. When you implement your function elsewhere you still have to provide the return type, which you've mistakenly left out:

```
/* void */ StringList::PrintOn() { ... }
```